# How to get number as alias in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

I have the below query:

```
Select 
  Y1 as Cast(v_FY0 - 5 - v_offset as char) 
from 
  TBLTMPLTS_LOAD_INCSTATEMT_RAW;
```

where 
      v_FY0 is NUMBER(10)
    and v_OffSet Number(10);

Upon executing, I get: `v_FY0 =2018 and v_OffSet = 0;`

So the statement becomes:

```
SELECT 
  Y1 as CAST(2018 - 5 - 0 AS CHAR) 
FROM 
  TBLTMPLTS_LOAD_INCSTATEMT_RAW;
```

Basically, what i am trying to achieve is upon selecting the column Y1 from table TBLTMPLTS_LOAD_INCSTATEMT_RAW the column name should be the calculated value of v_FY0 and v_OffSet as given in the above expression and i cannot write this directly as it runs in a loop and in the loop there are different values for v_FY0 and v_OffSet,thereby changing the column name everytime depending on the values of v_FY0 and v_OffSet.

But I am getting the error:

> ORA -00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

How to resolve this?

**EDIT:**
As said by Kaushik Nayak,the code which i presented above is part of the unpivot statement shown below.I had only took out the part which i felt was causing the issue to make everyone understand clearly.

```
v_SQL := '
-- ==========================================================
--  Main Unpivot Table -  To move years from column headings 
--  to rows values
-- ==========================================================

SELECT 
 CAST(FieldYear AS Number) FieldYear
, FieldType
, CASE FieldValue 
    WHEN '''' THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST (FieldValue AS Number(38,8))
  END FieldValue
FROM 
(SELECT ' || 
v_InsertType ||' AS FieldType
,Y1 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 - 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y2 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 - 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y3 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 - 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y4 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 - 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y5 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 - 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y6 as ' || CAST(v_FY0     - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || ' 
,Y7 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y8 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y9 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y10 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y11 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y12 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 6 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y13 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 7 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y14 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 8 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y15 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 9 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y16 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 10 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y17 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 11 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y18 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 12 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y19 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 13 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y20 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 14 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y21 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 15 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y22 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 16 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y23 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 17 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y24 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 18 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y25 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 19 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y26 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 20 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y27 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 21 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y28 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 22 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y29 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 23 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y30 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 24 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y31 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 25 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y32 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 26 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y33 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 27 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y34 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 28 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y35 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 29 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '

FROM ' || 
    v_tblInsertType || ') UP
UNPIVOT
(FieldValue FOR FieldYear IN 
(' || CAST(v_FY0 - 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 - 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 - 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 - 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 - 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0     - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 6 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 7 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 8 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 9 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 10 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 11 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 12 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 13 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 14 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 15 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 16 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 17 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 18 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 19 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 20 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 21 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 22 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 23 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 24 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 25 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 26 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 27 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 28 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 29 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
)
)AS unpvt

Execute immediate v_SQL;
```

But i am getting the error - ORA-00923: FROM Keyword not found where expected.

Comment: Not possible. The column alias has to be "constant"

Comment: It looks like your question is probably related to Pivoting (may be a dynamic one) but framed differently by stating the subset of the actual problem. Show some sample rows of your table with few more entries and tell us the desired output, it may be clear. This might  get you closer,  if not to the complete solution.

Comment: If you want dynamic column names, you might also want to look at DBMS_SQL.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I have copied the entire code here.

Answer (score 1):

Column names in the resultset are identifiers. Identifiers must be specified/known at the time the SQL statement is prepared.  It is not possible to have column names (column aliases) dynamically modified by or within the execution of the statement.

The normative approach to satisfying this type of requirement is to run *two* SQL  statements. The results from the first statement can be used in generating the text of second SQL statement.

---

**EDIT**

In the full code (added in a recent edit to the question), it seems like a final closing single quote is missing from the statement that assigns a value to `v_SQL`.

It seems like we would want the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to be a separate statement, and not part of the value assigned to `v_SQL`.

In the original question, it wasn't clear (to me) that the issue was in the context of a PL/SQL block i.e. `v_offset` is a reference to a PL/SQL variable rather than a column.

For debugging, consider DBMS_OUTPUT-ing the value of `v_SQL` immediately after the assignment.